# Vertx eventbus and verticle instances

Tags: vert.x, vertx-eventbus

We currently using 2 instances per verticle for our scaling needs, i just had a query regarding the evenBus publish.

If the eventBus publishes a message does this message get delivered to N instances of the verticle deployed?

```
DeploymentOptions().setInstances(2)
vertx.eventBus().publish("/event", Json.encodeToBuffer(message));
```

Comment: It depends, your question is too vague. It is possible to do make it work how ever you want, meaning deliver to all instances or only to 1 round robin. Specify if you using clustering or just DeploymentOptions().setInstances(4) and how you are publishing. It is possible to do point-to-point and publish/subscribe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is very short, I'll be very short too:

`eventBus.publish()` delivers the message to all listeners.

`eventBus.send()` delivers the message to a single listener.